# Getting error when I to try to install my program on Windows 2000

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am getting an error when I try to install my program (C# , Winforms, .NET 2.0) on Windows 2000:

> *The procedure entry point GetNativSystemInfo could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll*

Comment: `GetNativSystemInfo` (no "e") - I assume that's a typo?

Comment: The error occurs when running your installer right? If so you'll need to describe the installer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It the API you are using is simply not available at Windows 2000.

See also the [MSDN about `GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx):

> **Minimum supported client**
> Windows XP [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]
>
> **Minimum supported server**
> Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]

Why don't you use the function [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381.aspx) which is available for Windows 2000.

Comment: What you say is true but hardly helpful. Error appears to occur in the installer. Which is code not written by the poster. Since the poster didn't write the call to GetNativeSystemInfo, he/she can't easily change it.

Comment: @David Heffeman: the question does not specifically states that an installer has been used. This is just an assumption you make. The user may have "installed" the application by just copying the files from the "bin\Debug" folder. Furthermore, the poster might have written its own installer.

Comment: @Alexandre The question title seems clear enough to me. Also, a p/invoke would not result in load time error.